# perdida de estilos de layout a una vista

Tags: laravel, bootstrap, laravel-blade

Estoy trabajando en laravel con Adminlte y bootstrap. Tengo un `layout(adminlte)` dentro de la carpeta `/layouts`.

Se muestra bien y funciona con la vista `home` y tambien con 3 `index` que tengo en tres carpetas diferentes, se muestra todo correcto.

Mis vistas extienden `@extends('layouts.layout')` y el código propio de cada vista.

El problema es al pasar a otra vista de cualquiera de las tres carpetas, que no sea el `home` u alguno de los `index`, se muestra todo en desorden, pierde a mi parecer los estilos.

En el layout tengo para content `@yield('content')`, y en las vista con `@extends('layouts.layout')`.

Para hacer pruebas he dejado solamente el `@extends('layouts.layout')` y un hola mundo bajo él, y pierde igualmente todos los estilos.

Comment: Pero está poniendo `@section('content')` en las vistas "hijas"? Por ejemplo el hola mundo,¿ tienes algo así?: `@extends('layouts.layout')  @section('content') Hola Mundo @endsection`.  ¿O está poniendo directamente `@extends('layouts.layout')   Hola Mundo `?

Comment: justamente como tu primera opcion

Comment: es mas, el layout funciona con el index, duplique este ultimo y solo le cambie nombre, igual da el mismo error, se pierden los estilos, no soy experto, mas bien principiante, pero esto no me cuadra

Comment: solucionado, eran las rutas absolutas de los css en el layout, solucionado con "{{ asset(' ')}}